# Having problems with cstring arrays

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with my code with something with arrays. I am getting the following errors

```
In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
75: error: cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘char (*)[81]’ for argument ‘1’                                                                  ion(char (*)[81], OneItem*, int&, int&)’
 In function ‘void parseInformation(char (*)[81], OneItem*, int&, in
164: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
166: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char [2]’ to
169: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
174: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
174: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer
176: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’
```

The code doesn't line up with the line numbers. I have tried multiple things googled some things still haven't found a solution.

```
const int MAX_CHARACTERS = 80;
    const int MAX_INVENTORY = 12;

    typedef char OneLine[MAX_CHARACTERS + 1];
    struct OneItem
    {
        char product[MAX_CHARACTERS + 1];
        int quantity;
        float unitPrice;
        float totalPrice;
    };



    int main( const int argc, const char* argv[] )
    {

        OneLine fileName;
        ifstream inFile;

        OneLine readLine;
        OneItem inventory[MAX_INVENTORY];


        int readLineIndex;
        int structureCounter = 0;
        int averageQuantity;
        float averagePrice;
        float averageTotalPrice;

        displayIntroduction();

        getFileName( argc, argv, fileName );
        if (!inFile)
        {
            cout << "File not found: " << fileName << endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            inFile.open(fileName);
            while(!inFile.getline(readLine, MAX_CHARACTERS, '\n').eof())
            {
                if (structureCounter < MAX_INVENTORY)
                {
                    parseInformation(readLine,inventory, readLineIndex, structureCounter);
                }
            }

void parseInformation(OneLine readLine[],OneItem inventory[], int & readLineIndex, int & structureCounter)
{
    int tempIndex = 0;
    int valueCounter = 0;
    OneLine tempArray;
    while(readLine[readLineIndex] != '\n')
    {
        tempArray = "\0";


        while(readLine[readLineIndex] == ' ')
        {
            readLineIndex += 1;

        }
        while(readLine[readLineIndex] != ' ' && readLine[readLineIndex] != '\n')
        {   
            tempArray[tempIndex] = readLine[readLineIndex];
            tempIndex += 1;
            readLineIndex += 1;
        }
        if(valueCounter == 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= strlen(tempArray); i++)
            {
                inventory[structureCounter].product[i] = tempArray[i];
            }
            valueCounter += 1;
        }
        else if(valueCounter == 1)
        {
            inventory[structureCounter].quantity = atoi(tempArray);
            valueCounter += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            inventory[structureCounter].unitPrice = atof(tempArray);
            structureCounter += 1;
        }



    }
    return;
```

Comment: Put the error messages into the question as plain text, not as a link to an inage.

Comment: The first argument to `parseInformation` is supposed to be an array of `OneLine`, but `readLine` is not an array.

Comment: @Barmar now wouldn't that make `fileName` not an cstring array? It uses the same typedef but I have no errors on that when I use strncopy using `fileName`

Comment: `strncpy` expects its argument to be a cstring, not an array of cstrings.

Comment: @Barmar I have this line in the function getFileName `strncpy( fileName, argv[1], strlen( argv[1] ) + 1);`

Comment: What's the problem with that? `fileName` is a `cstring`, `strncpy` expects its first argument to be a `cstring`.

Comment: So what will I need to change to fix this? Because `readLine` is supposed to be a cstring copied from an external data file and then I extract values from that line.

Comment: Do you know [johndoe1213124](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5348655/jondoe1213124) or [DrakeJacks](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4700209/drakejacks)? You've all posted questions today that are asking about very similar code.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `parseInformation` is wrong. It says that `readLine` should be an array of `OneLine`, but it only wants a single `OneLine`. It should be:

```
void parseInformation(OneLine readLine,OneItem inventory[], int & readLineIndex, int & structureCounter)
```

This is causing all the errors you're getting, because you're calling the function with a single `OneLine`, not an array. And inside the function you're comparing `readLine[readLineIndex]` with a character, which requires `readLine` to be an array of characters, not an array of `OneLine`.

The `OneLine` typedef makes this an array already, you didn't need to add `[]` to the parameter declaration.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar said you need to change first argument, but there is one more problem, here:

```
OneLine tempArray;
while(readLine[readLineIndex] != '\n')
{
    tempArray = "\0";
```

You cannot make such assign. `tempArray` needs to be of type `const char*` or you need to make it this way:

```
tempArray[some_index] = '\0';
```